# Who to serialize/deserialize List<Tuple<long, string, int>> using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, javascriptserializer

I have serialized a `List<Tuple<long, string, int>> obj` using JavaScriptSerializer.

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return js.Serialize(dataToSerialize as IEnumerable);
```

and I got the string:

```
[{"Item1":0,"Item2":"UserModifiedId","Item3":1},{"Item1":-1,"Item2":"","Item3":0},{"Item1":-1,"Item2":"","Item3":0}]
```

When I try to deserialize it using:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return js.Deserialize<List<T>>(strObject);
```

I get the following ex:

````
No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Tuple`3[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.```

Can anyone help me with this Issue (to keep using JavaScriptSerializer)?
````

Comment: Don't use JavaScriptSerializer. It's obsolete. Even ASP.NET Web API and all ASP.NET Core versions up to 2.2 use Json.NET. It's the defacto standard JSON library in .NET. Beyond that, you need to specify the type during deserialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JavaScriptSerializer` needs a parameterless constructor to create the objects during deserialization.

Because the class `Tuple` has none, the deserialization fails.

If you don't bother you can use the `NuGet` package `Newtonsoft.Json`, which doesn't have his problem:

```
var strObject= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSerialize);

var tupleList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tuple<long, string, int>>>(strObject);
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to use Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Then you might have to look into `DataContractJsonSerializer`, as I am afraid `JavaScriptSerializer` won't work in this case.

Comment: Thnx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the exact type when deserializing

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return js.Deserialize<List<Tuple<long, string, int>>>(strObject);
```

Comment: This still suffers from the same problem.

Comment: I tried that, I got the same exception. (Thnx for the answer)